# Question on the unique irreducible quotient of a standard module

Tags: representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $F$ be a local field of characteristic zero and $\chi$ be a character of $GL_1(F)$.

Let $\pi$ be the normalized parabolic induction from the character $\chi |\cdot|^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \times \chi |\cdot|^{\frac{n-1}{2}-1} \times \cdots \times \chi |\cdot|^{\frac{1-n}{2}}$ of $GL_1(F)^n$ to $GL_n(F)$.

Then I don't know why $\chi (det)$ should be the (unique) irreducible quotient of $\pi$.

Could you anyone explain this to me?

Comment: What have you done? Can you find an invariant line?

Comment: @Kimball, If $\pi$ was the normalized parabolic induction from the character $\chi |\cdot|^{\frac{1-n}{2}} \times \chi |\cdot|^{\frac{1-n}{2}+1} \times \cdots \times \chi |\cdot|^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ of $GL_1(F)^n$ to $GL_n(F)$, I checked that it has a sub representation $\chi(det)$ because $|\cdot|^{\frac{1-n}{2}} \times |\cdot|^{\frac{1-n}{2}+1} \times \cdots \times |\cdot|^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ is the -half exponent of the modulus character of Borel subgroup and so its parabolic induction contains an identity function on $GL_n(F)$. But I don’t know about the quotient.